# NoneType object is not iterable error in pandas

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

I am trying to pull some data from a stored proc on a sql server using python.

Here is my code:

```
import datetime as dt
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL Server Native client 11.0}',server = '*****, database = '**')

pd.read_sql("EXEC ******** '20140528'",conn)
```

I get the error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

I suspect this is because I have a cell in the sql table with value NULL but not sure if that's the true reason why I am getting the error. I have run many sql statements using the same code without any errors.

Here's the traceback:

```
In[39]: pd.read_sql("EXEC [dbo].[] '20140528'",conn)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:*", line 3032, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-39-68fb1c956dd7>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.read_sql("EXEC [dbo].[] '20140528'",conn)
  File "C:*", line 467, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize
  File "c:***", line 1404, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Can you post the full error code?

Comment: are certain that your query is valid? what's different about this block of code than the others that work?

Comment: I can see a lot of unmatched closing quotes for strings `", '`?

Comment: Can you show the output of directly doing conn.execute("EXEC ..") and then fetchall() ? Are you sure it returns anything?

Comment: package are able to handle sql NULL, most likely is some error in your query. If you're using microsoft sql server have a look at mssql package which works without setting up odbc connecting :)

Comment: @SuperBiasedMan - Here is the full error code:

In[39]: pd.read_sql("EXEC [dbo].[***] '20140528'",conn)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\***", line 3032, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-39-68fb1c956dd7>", line 1, in <module>
    pd.read_sql("EXEC [dbo].[***] '20140528'",conn)
  File "C:\***", line 467, in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
  File "c:\***", line 1404, in read_query
    columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Comment: @joris: I tried this:

conn.execute("EXEC [dbo].[***] '2015-05-28'").fetchall()
Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Connection is busy with results for another command (0) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Comment: Your object, `cursor.description` is being set as `None`, you'll have to investigate what should be providing an iterable there and why it's failing to.

Comment: What's wierd is that I can't figure out why the other commands have worked but this one is not working. Those stored proc also had NULL values. The format of the columns is also similar (dateTime).

Answer (score 30):

Your sproc needs

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
```

Without this `sql` will return the `rowcount` for the call, which will come back without a column name, causing the `NoneType` error.

Comment: I've also encountered this issue using temp tables in my queries. This method will also fix.

Comment: Yes, this worked for me. I didn't need to use it for pymssql but needed it for pyodbc.

Answer (score 6):

`pd.read_sql()` expects to have output to return, and tries to iterate through the output; that's where the `TypeError` is coming from. Instead, execute with a cursor object:

```
import datetime as dt
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes', driver = '{SQL Server Native client 11.0}',server = '*****', database = '**')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("EXEC ******** '20140528'")
```

You won't receive any output, but since none is expected, your code should run without error.

Answer (score 1):

It's way too late for the post,
But i encountered the same error,after searching lot on stack-overflow found that its not an issue with pandas/python  but with the query/stored proc

My workaround was Debugging the python script and step into built-in code of pandas,
reach till this path `site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py` , there your will see this code

```
cursor=self.execute(*args)
```

Execute this line with debugger and view the cursor object , you will find  what is getting returned by the stored proc, in my case there was an irrelevant message i was triggering from stored proc

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime as dt
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

conn = pyodbc.connect('Trusted_Connection=yes; driver =SQL Server Native client 
11.0; server = *****, database = **')
sqlSend = conn.cursor()
sqlSend.execute(f"EXEC ******** '20140528'")
conn.commint()
```