# Executing sequence of MS sql queries with temp tables in python

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, pyodbc

Currently trying to use `pyodbc` and `pandas` to read sequence of sql queries (from `MS sql server`) and examine as dataframe, getting the following error on the very first query in the sequence:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-95-5eec1638614b> in <module>()
    285 for count, q in enumerate(sql_in):
    286     print count
--> 287     frame_in = pd.read_sql(q, cnxn)
    288 print frame_in.head(n=10)
    289 

/home/mapr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in read_sql(sql, con, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, columns, chunksize)
    497             sql, index_col=index_col, params=params,
    498             coerce_float=coerce_float, parse_dates=parse_dates,
--> 499             chunksize=chunksize)
    500 
    501     try:

/home/mapr/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.pyc in read_query(self, sql, index_col, coerce_float, params, parse_dates, chunksize)
   1598         args = _convert_params(sql, params)
   1599         cursor = self.execute(*args)
-> 1600         columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
   1601 
   1602         if chunksize is not None:

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

The relevant code snippet looks like:

```
sql_in = """
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select <stuff> from <table1> into #<temptable1>
----SPLIT
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select <stuff> from <table2> into #<temptable2>
----SPLIT
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select <stuff> from <table3> into #<temptable3>
----SPLIT
SET NOCOUNT ON;
select <stuff> from <table4> <joined with temptables1-3> into #<temptable4>
""".split('----SPLIT')

for count, q in enumerate(sql_in):
    print count
    frame_in = pd.read_sql(q, cnxn)
```

Done this way because only interested in the final temp table (using `split` because of the advice posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34881248)).

Can confirm that pyodbc is configured right by running:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()

#Sample select query
print 'Testing db connection...'
cursor.execute("SELECT @@version;") 
row = cursor.fetchone() 
while row: 
    print row[0] 
    row = cursor.fetchone()
```

And actually getting the server version.

Any ideas why this could be happening and how to fix? Thanks.

Comment: I believe the DB-API specifies that `.execute()` allows only one query per command.

Comment: @bernie - I just had another look at [PEP249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) and I see no mention of that. Certainly an anonymous code block (multi-statement batch) *can* work if the ODBC driver allows it (and Microsoft's ODBC Driver for SQL Server does allow it).

Comment: Ah, ok. Thanks @GordThompson. I must be mistaken then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is because the first several queries don't return any data. Pandas read_sql expects data to come back. You should just use the pyodbc execute function to run those queries.

Comment: ... or perhaps try passing the whole anonymous code block (without splitting it) to `read_sql`? (Can't try it right now; no pandas on my phone....)

Comment: that would work better, I was just trying to answer the question of why their code wasn't working

Comment: This post answers the original question of why the code was not working, though ultimately ended up implementing the solution suggested by user GordThompson. Thank you to both.

Comment: Isn't it also `SELECT <stuff> INTO #<temptable1> FROM <table1>`? I believe the order of your `INTO` / `FROM` are reversed in your raw SQL.

Comment: @FlipperPA I'm using MS SQL Server, so the way it is posted works for me.