# Pandas read_sql inconsistent behaviour dependent on driver?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, freetds

When I run a query from my local machine to a SQL server db, data is returned. If I run the same query from a JupyterHub server (using ssh), the following is returned:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Implying it isn't getting any data.

The connection string is OK on both systems (albeit different), because running the same stored procedure works fine on both systems using the connection string -

`Local= "Driver={SQL Server};Server=DNS-based-address;Database=name;uid=user;pwd=pwd"`

`Hub = "DRIVER=FreeTDS;SERVER=IP.add.re.ss;PORT=1433;DATABASE=name;UID=dbuser;PWD=pwd;TDS_Version=8.0"`

Is there something in the FreeTDS driver that affects chunksize, or means a set nocount is required in the original query as per this [NoneType object is not iterable error in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534095/nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-error-in-pandas) - I tried this fix by the way and got nowhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using `pymssql`, which is build on top of FreeTDS?

For SQL-Server you could also try the Microsoft JDBC Driver with the python package `jaydebeapi`: https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-jdbc.

```
import pandas as pd
import pymssql

conn = pymssql.connect(
    host = r'192.168.254.254',
    port = '1433',
    user = r'user',
    password = r'password',
    database = 'DB_NAME'
)

query = """SELECT * FROM db_table"""

df = pd.read_sql(con=conn, sql=query)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @kafran, really very appreciated. I've been using pyodbc - which works fine with the stored procs, not sure why not for this - any idea? Thanks again

Comment: `pyodbc` runs on top of `unixODBC` which can use either FreeTDS or the MS ODBC driver in a Linux environment. I note that you're using `TDS_Version=8.0` in your connection string; this is not a valid TDS Version, and maps to version 7.1. You might want to try `TDS_Version=7.3` depending on your version of FreeTDS. It is a bit confusing, but have a look here: https://www.freetds.org/userguide/choosingtdsprotocol.htm

Comment: For those who come here from Google, pymssql is now discontinued in favour of pyodbc. See https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/668

Comment: I wouldn't say pymssql is being discontinued in favor of pyodbc. It is being discontinued (period). There are alternatives like ctds, a pretty good one, based on FreeTDS with support for bulk load.