# Python 'NoneType' error when insert into a variable table in stored procedure

Tags: python, sql-server

This is my Python code

```
import pymssql
import pyodbc 


pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', 300)

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DELLG3\SQLEXPRESS;'
                      'Database=MIMIC;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')


df = pd.read_sql("EXEC spReps 1" , conn)
```

This is my SQL Server stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spReps @N int
AS
BEGIN


    DECLARE @Temp AS Table (S numeric(18,0), H numeric(18,0), D varchar(8000))

    INSERT INTO @Temp (S, H, D)
    values(1,2,3)

    SELECT 1

    END
```

This is giving me error on python

> File "C:\Users\myuser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py",
>   line 1469, in read_query
>       columns = [col_desc[0] for col_desc in cursor.description]
>
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

but when I comment out the insert into the variable table

it works fine

the SP then looks like this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE spReps @N int
AS
BEGIN


    DECLARE @Temp AS Table (S numeric(18,0), H numeric(18,0), D varchar(8000))

    SELECT 1

    END
```

Note : this is a sample of what i want to do, the SP is way bigger and I have to use variable table

I want to know what is causing the error and how to stop it.

Comment: Why does your SP (`spReps`) have the parameter `@N` when it's never used?

Comment: @Larnu it is a sample of the actual SP  this parameter is used in the script, i just simplified it

Comment: I am not an expert in sql server, but try `values(1,2,'3')`

Comment: That won't change anything , @AnatoliyR, SQL Server was already implicitly converting `3` to a `varchar`.

Comment: the fact that the problem is stored procedure, this is not python issue, so need to try everything.... but I am not a fan of sql server, so don't know

Comment: But, by the OP's own admission, @AnatoliyR , the SP we have isn't their actual SP (/facepalm).

Comment: @AnatoliyR SQL Server SP returns the same value in both scripts

Comment: ah, then you probably need to add more detail to the question, because the error you get is from python

Comment: @AnatoliyR this is all script needed to duplicated the error. further details will be distraction

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NoneType object is not iterable error in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534095/nonetype-object-is-not-iterable-error-in-pandas)